# How to Validate Data issue for fixed length file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, fixed-width

I am reading a fixed-width file in mapping Data Flow and loading it to the table. I want to validate the fields, datatype, lengths of the field that I am extracting in the Derived column using substring.
How to Achieve this in ADF

Answer (score 0):

Use a Conditional Split and add a condition for each property of the field that you wish to test for. For data type checking, we literally just landed new isInteger(), isString() ... functions today. The docs are still in the printing press, but you'll find them in the expression builder. For length use length().